# Cant install sonata admin with symfony 5

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

$ composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle
Using version ^3.87 for sonata-project/admin-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update sonata-project/admin-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.2.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

**Problem 1

- sonata-project/admin-bundle[3.87.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require symfony/console ^4.4 -> found 
symfony/console[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (5.2.*).

- Root composer.json requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ^3.87 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[3.87.0, 3.x-dev].**

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear?

Answer (score 1):

According to [an issue from their tracker](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/6365#issuecomment-752923319) and [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/admin-bundle#3.87.0), the most recent version of that package (which is 3.87.0) is not fully compatible with Symfony 5. You either need to wait until this is resolved, or downgrade Symfony in your application to v4.4

Comment: Nico Haase, how to downgrade?

Comment: By requiring another version of Symfony. As you haven't shared your `composer.json`, I cannot provide any further help

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use EasyAdmin bundle which is compatible with Symfony 5.3. It has only one bug which is related to viewing images thumbnail in easyadmin panel. For now the only solution is to use TextareaField instead of ImageField in DasboardCrudController.